# Allow IIS Cors requests

Tags: flutter, rest, google-chrome, cors

I have a rest api hosted on windows server IIS 10.
I have a website hosted on Apache servers.
service: https://servis.vass.net.tr
web: https://www.vass.net.tr

The web project was written with flutter web.

Origin is set to https://www.vass.net.tr in cors settings.

While testing my application, since web security is turned off, I send a request without any problems and the result is returned.
However, after publishing the application, I get the following error.(only for Chrome browsers)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://servis.vass.net.tr/token' from origin 'https://www.vass.net.tr' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Web Config Setting :

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /></handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://www.vass.net.tr" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, expiry, uid, access-token, token-type, myguid, device, Authorization" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

I installed the Microsoft.AspNet.Cors nuget package

I enabled cors at api startup and wrote the response method for OPTIONS requests

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://www.vass.net.tr", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        }

    }

    public class OptionsHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Options)
            {
                var apiExplorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();

                var controllerRequested = request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"] as string;
                var supportedMethods = apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions.Where(d =>
                {
                    var controller = d.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
                    return string.Equals(
                        controller, controllerRequested, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                })
                .Select(d => d.HttpMethod.Method)
                .Distinct();

                if (!supportedMethods.Any())
                    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
                        () => request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));

                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    resp.Headers.Add(
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", string.Join(",", supportedMethods));

                    return resp;
                });
            }

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You most likely meant `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` instead of `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`.